# MongoDB vs DynamoDB in Amazon cloud?

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, nosql

DynamoDB is key-value based NoSQL and no maintenance is requires except throughput(read and write) provisioning on each table. Data replication is done automatically behind the scene.

I can see very less maintenance in DynamoDB.

Should i use MongoDB for any good reason in cloud?

What are the usecases where MongoDB is better than DynamoDB?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a very subjective question - without any context, its impossible for anyone to recommend which to use.

Which database is best for you depends on a wide range of things, including but not limited to

- Read patterns
- Write patterns
- Query complexity
- Scalability requirements
- Adoption rates
- Language support
- Commercial support
- Durability
- Transaction support
- Data integrity
- Plenty more

You need to think about your application and understand things like what I've listed above and figure out what you need out of a database.  Then you need to understand each of your options and which will suffice.